# How to replace certain columns in a file of uneven dimensions

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to edit some data in a txt file, but the file is written such that there are some rows with more columns than others. Example:

```
      1  0.0   0.
      2  0.25  0.
      3  0.50  0.  13   1   0.2  0.
     14 2.625  0.
     15 2.800  0.  20  1    0.2
     21 4.05  0.
     22 4.2    0.  24   1   0.2
     25 4.75  0.
     26 4.90
     27 5.05
     28 5.15
     29 5.25
```

As can be seen, there are sections with multiple spaces, and some rows have 7 columns instead of 3. 
I want to take each value from the second column (0.0, 0.25, etc) and from the sixth column (0.2, 0.2, etc) and perform basic multiplication and division on each. So for example, in the second row, I want to take 0.25 and multiply it by 25.4.

I tried to read and break the file into a list

```py
g = open("myfile.txt","r+")
lines = g.read().split(' ')
while('' in lines):
    lines.remove('')
```

This gives the output

```
    ['1', '0.0', '0.\n', '2', '0.25', '0.\n', '3', '0.50', '0.', '13', '1', '0.2', 
    '0.\n', '14', '2.625', '0.\n', '15', '2.800', '0.', '20', '1', '0.2\n', '21', 
    '4.05', '0.\n', '22', '4.2', '0.', '24', '1', '0.2\n', '25', '4.75', '0.\n', '26', 
    '4.90\n', '27', '5.05\n', '28', '5.15\n', '29', '5.25\n\n']
```

(The second \n at the end is because there are empty rows to space each section of this data). I then tried to use a loop and counter to define where each item in the list is in the table:

```py
counter = 0
for i in lines:
    if '\n' in lines[i]:
        counter = 0
    elif counter == 1 or counter == 5:
        lines[i] = float(lines[i])*25.4

    counter += 1
```

From this, I end up with the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Any ideas on what I could do that would work, and potentially be more elegant?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution for your problem if I understood it correctly:

Use `with open() as f` sintax to make sure your file will be closed after the scope ended.

```
lines = list()
with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip() # clean possible additional spaces just to be sure
        lines.append(line.split())
```

to multiply the values you want in place:

```
for line in lines:
    line[1] = line[1]*25.4
    line[5] = line[5]*25.4
```

hope it helped

Comment: I'm glad it worked out! Please consider setting this as the correct answer than.

Comment: @twalker it's a good practice to mark the right answer and close the question